# ideal method of building tables in PHP

Tags: php

As an intern I realized that I spend the bulk of my time building and manipulating tables from sql queries in PHP. My current method is to use two foreach loops:

```
foreach($query as $record){
    foreach($record as $field => $value){
        *Things that need to be done on each field-value pair*
    }
    *Things that need to be done on each row*
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Also I tend to pack data together as a ~ separated list and store it in the server, is this a bad practice?

I'd rather put some code up for review but I don't want to risk exposing the internals of the company cod.

Comment: You probably shouldn't store comma-separated data in a database server, as you'll lose all the advantages of said server, like querying, etc.

Comment: Storing delimited lists in databases is also often an indicator that you're violating [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), and you should try to restructure tables to satisfy [third normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

Comment: Why do you need the second loop? I don't see any benefits to that unless you have a variable number of fields that you select. Do you realise you should be able to access the data with `$record['field']` if it's an associative array?

Comment: Hey there, if you do ever feel like getting someone to review your code I totally and unbiasedly recommend this site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sometimes I have to print out the names of the fields and values to form a simple table or do other things with the field names. Thats why use a second loop usually.

Also I would post some more detailed code there but sadly I do not own it so I'd rather not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreach loops are the best way to iterate through your data. If you are looking to make your code a bit prettier, try using the ternary version

```
<?php foreach($query as $record) : ?>
   <?php foreach($record as $field => $value) : ?>
        *Things that need to be done on each field-value pair*
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    *Things that need to be done on each row*
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Also, like mentioned in the comments above, you lose a lot of functionality when storing ~ seperated data in the db. If you must do this, you can try storing serialized objects instead of delimited strings. You can manipulate the objects in a number of ways such as [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
   $myArray = array();
    $myArray['User1']['book'] = 'Pride and Prejudice';
    $myArray['User1']['favorites'] = 'Water skiing';
    $myArray['User2']['book'] = 'Mansfield Park';
    $myArray['User2']['favorites'] = array('skateboarding', 'surfing', 'running');
    $myArray['description'] = 'Things people like.';        

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(json_encode($myArray)); //This will convert your array to a string for the db
    echo '</pre>';

    echo '<pre>';
    $myArrayString = json_encode($myArray);
    print_r(json_decode($myArrayString)); //This will convert the db string to an object for manipulation

echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Hmm what are the advantages of using a serialized string in a database? I do need to store the values of <option> tags in the db from time to time and that's how I started using the ~ lists.

Comment: I like to use serialized json objects because you can easily convert the string to a json object in php and javascript which is nice when making ajax requests. Also, the main benefit that you don't get with comma delimited is the hierarchical data. I will update my answer to give you a simple example with associative array to try out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to produce a HTML table from the result of a query. If you find yourself writing that sort of code over and over, then it would be a good candidate to make a reusable class or library. For example:

```
$table = new HTMLTable();
$table->setData($data);
echo $table->toHTML();
```

The above is not working code, just an example of how you could create reusable code instead of repeating the same table building code many times.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a `while` loop with one of the `mysql_fetch_..` functions. But essentially it's the same as what you do.

```
$query = 'SELECT
            stuff
          FROM
            table';
if ($query = mysql_query($query)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            /* Things that need to be done on each field-value pair */
        }
        /* Things that need to be done on each row */
    }
}
```

And as to the ~ separated list. I strongly recommend to save the data in separate DB fields, instead of packing it like that. Just create a new table for each such pack.